# Ethernet not recognized on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, ethernet

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 (Windows 11 dual boot) using kernel verion 6.5.0-21-generic. I am running this version of the kernel because it appears that the intel wireless driver is incompatible with 6.5.0-26-generic, as per [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1507264/ubuntu-22-repeated-wireless-reset-by-kernel). I am trying to connect to a wired network now, but it is not working. By my understanding, there is something wrong with the driver for the ethernet controller: when I run `sudo lshw -C network`, the output is:

```
*-network                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:6d:00.0
   logical name: wlp109s0f0
   version: 1a
   serial: 4c:49:6c:37:68:92
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=6.5.0-21-generic firmware=83.ec13314b.0 gl-c0-fm-c0-83.uc ip=10.27.242.187 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes
   resources: irq:19 memory:a7200000-a7203fff

*-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Ethernet controller
   product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:6e:00.0
   version: 02
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a7100000-a710ffff memory:a7110000-a7113fff
```

There are a number of questions that seem to address this issue: [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437477/22-04-1-network-unclaimed) [2](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/705739)

The solutions therein did not work for me. I have already tried installing `linux-generic-hwe-22.04` and `linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-21-generic`. Unfortunately, I am at a loss at this point. Any help is appreciated!